# Unable to build TensorFlow from source with bazel. 22nd January 2016

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I wanted to install the latest TensorFlow from source. I pulled the repository, and then ran

`bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

I got this error:

```
ERROR: /home/samuelchin/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/embedding/BUILD:10:6: First argument of load() is a path, not a label. It should start with a single slash if it is an absolute path.
ERROR: /home/samuelchin/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/embedding/BUILD:10:6: file '/tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl.bzl' was not correctly loaded. Make sure the 'load' statement appears in the global scope in your file.
ERROR: /home/samuelchin/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/embedding/BUILD:104:1: name 'tf_gen_op_wrapper_py' is not defined.
ERROR: /home/samuelchin/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:13:1: Target '//tensorflow/models/embedding:package' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package'.
ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.071s.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a recent change to the TensorFlow `BUILD` files that causes the dependency on Bazel 0.1.4. This was [announced](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss/qUech_YUtCM/h4IDS38yCQAJ) on the `discuss@tensorflow.org` mailing list, but hasn't made it into the documentation on the website yet.

As you have already discovered, upgrading Bazel to [version 0.1.4](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.1.4) should fix this build error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that bazel was outdated. The previous version of my bazel was 0.1.2, which was last updated in December. Bazel has since then been updated to 0.1.4. For those who have this error, updating bazel would do the trick. You can then build as per normal.

I guess in future, if it can't build, you might want to check if bazel is updated to the latest version.

Comment: I would not specifically recommend the latest version. IIRC there was period of time when Bazel 0.1.1 would work and 0.1.2 would not work and at the time 0.1.2 was the latest version. It is the specific versions that work and not the latest version. I know the Bazel group has been paying more attention to having Bazel work consistently for the public version of TensorFlow, but I do not know the details.